# SQL Server Invalid Column Name Error

Tags: sql-server

I have an invalid Column Name error when inserting a record to my SQL Server table. Here's the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable] 
(
    [id] int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [person_name] varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    [modified_By] varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
ON [PRIMARY] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);
GO
```

And insert

```
INSERT INTO myDB.dbo.myTable (id, person_name, modified_By) 
VALUES (1, 'Aishwarya', 'admin')
```

But I get the following error upon execution:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Invalid column name
>   'modified_BY'.

I can `SELECT` from the column fine. The only thing I've noticed in error is that "BY" is capitalized, contrary to the table definition. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Updating all the syntax errors, apologeez

Comment: missing `]` after `person_name` and after `modified_by`

Comment: missing ) which is supposed to close the create table

Comment: Is that the actual code and context that gave you the error? It seems unlikely.

Comment: There's all sorts of stuff going on here.  As @jpw pointed out, I doubt this is your actual code.  Surely person_name isn't an integer?  Are you using [ ] in your actual insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

Is your database set to a case sensitive collation?  You can check by running this query:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('<Insert Database Name>', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

Case insensitive collations usually have CI in the name, such as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Where as case sensitive collation might be something like `Latin1_General_BIN`.

If the database has a case sensitive collation, then the capitalization in the T-SQL must match the column definition.

Your post here doesn't include the `modified_BY` capitalization in the insert statement, so double check that.  If it's capitalized there properly, then check if there are any triggers on the table that might have the improper spelling.

Comment: Mine DB Returns Latin1_General_CI_AS - haven't searched this yet but I'm guessing that's case insensitive?

Comment: This is defined on my `modified_By` column as well

Comment: The fact that the error message has a different capitalization is fishy.  Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes there are triggers on the table, but my DBA dropped and recreated all  the table and it appears to have resolved the issue. Pretty nonconstructive has he hasn't told us why

Comment: Ah, so it was trigger code generating the error.  Well hopefully it wasn't essential!

Answer (score 0):

In your INSERT statement do not supply a value for your IDENTITY column "Id". It should look like:

```
INSERT INTO myDB.dbo.myTable
(person_name, modified_By) 
VALUES ('Aishwarya', 'admin')
```

Comment: Sure enough, but that shouldn't render the error message the OP claims to have.

Comment: You're right. But I'm guessing that that will be the next error he/she will encounter :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer anyone wants to hear, but our DBA dropped and recreated the table (which had triggers set on it) and this has resolved the issue.